# Unable to assume role and validate the specified targetGroupArn

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to create and deploy a cluster using terraform ecs_service, but am unable to do so. My `terraform apply`s always fail around IAM roles, which I don't clearly understand. Specifically, the error message is:

> InvalidParametersException: Unable to assume role and validate the specified targetGroupArn. Please verify that the ECS service role being passed has the proper permissions.

And I have found that:

1. When I have `iam_role` specified in ecs_service, ECS complains that I need to use a service-linked role.
2. When I have `iam_role` commented in ecs_service, ECS complains that the assumed role cannot validate the targetGroupArn.

My terraform spans a bunch of files. I pulled what feels like the relevant portions out below. Though I *have* seen a few similar problems posted, none have provided an actionable solution that solves the dilemma above, for me.

```
## ALB

resource "aws_alb" "frankly_internal_alb" {
    name = "frankly-internal-alb"
    internal = false
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.frankly_internal_alb_sg.id}"]
    subnets = ["${aws_subnet.frankly_public_subnet_a.id}", "${aws_subnet.frankly_public_subnet_b.id}"]
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "frankly_alb_listener" {
    load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.frankly_internal_alb.arn}"

    port = "8080"
    protocol = "HTTP"

    default_action {
        target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.frankly_internal_target_group.arn}"
        type = "forward"
    }
}

## Target Group

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "frankly_internal_target_group" {
    name = "internal-target-group"
    port = 8080
    protocol = "HTTP"
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.frankly_vpc.id}"

    health_check {
        healthy_threshold = 5
        unhealthy_threshold = 2
        timeout = 5
    }
}

## IAM

resource "aws_iam_role" "frankly_ec2_role" {
  name               = "franklyec2role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "frankly_ecs_role" {
  name = "frankly_ecs_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

# aggresively add permissions...
resource "aws_iam_policy" "frankly_ecs_policy" {
  name        = "frankly_ecs_policy"
  description = "A test policy"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:*",
        "ecs:*",
        "ecr:*",
        "autoscaling:*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:*",
        "application-autoscaling:*",
        "logs:*",
        "tag:*",
        "resource-groups:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "frankly_ecs_attach" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.frankly_ecs_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.frankly_ecs_policy.arn}"
}

## ECS

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "frankly_ec2" {
    name = "frankly_ec2_cluster"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "frankly_ecs_task" {
  family                = "service"
  container_definitions = "${file("terraform/task-definitions/search.json")}"

  volume {
    name      = "service-storage"

    docker_volume_configuration {
      scope         = "shared"
      autoprovision = true
    }
  }

  placement_constraints {
    type       = "memberOf"
    expression = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone in [us-east-1]"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "frankly_ecs_service" {
  name            = "frankly_ecs_service"
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.frankly_ec2.id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.frankly_ecs_task.arn}"
  desired_count   = 2
  iam_role        = "${aws_iam_role.frankly_ecs_role.arn}"
  depends_on      = ["aws_iam_role.frankly_ecs_role", "aws_alb.frankly_internal_alb", "aws_alb_target_group.frankly_internal_target_group"]

  # network_configuration = {
  #   subnets = ["${aws_subnet.frankly_private_subnet_a.id}", "${aws_subnet.frankly_private_subnet_b}"]
  #   security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.frankly_internal_alb_sg}", "${aws_security_group.frankly_service_sg}"]
  #   # assign_public_ip = true
  # }

  ordered_placement_strategy {
    type  = "binpack"
    field = "cpu"
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.frankly_internal_target_group.arn}"
    container_name   = "search-svc"
    container_port   = 8080
  }

  placement_constraints {
    type       = "memberOf"
    expression = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone in [us-east-1]"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show more context around the `apply` error? Is it the `aws_ecs_service` resource throwing that? Can you also show the Terraform code for the ECS cluster instances?

Comment: I'm experiencing this precise problem. Running a `terraform destroy` and then re-applying does not work.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I was seeing an identical error message and I was doing something else wrong:

I had specified the loadbalancer's ARN and *not* the loadbalancer's target_group ARN.

Comment: you save my day!

Comment: you save my day too!

Comment: However in the resource "aws_ecs_service" "frankly_ecs_service" the load balancer section have correctly the Target Group ARN: "${aws_alb_target_group.frankly_internal_target_group.arn}"

Comment: @MiguelConde Yeah I think what this is is a bad error message. I certainly wouldn't say this is the only reason you might get this message. It seems like you may be hitting it for a different reason.

Comment: At my case was because I forgot add an aws_iam_role_policy_attachment resource

Comment: If I could upvote this some more, I would! I had this issue when deploying a new ECS service and one of the target groups had an invalid name.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that I forgot to attach the right policy to the service role. Attaching this AWS-managed policy helped: `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole`

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent the error:

```
Error: creating ECS Service (*****): InvalidParameterException: Unable to assume role and validate the specified targetGroupArn. Please verify that the ECS service role being passed has the proper permissions.
```

From my side is working with the following configuration:

1. Role Trusted relationship: Adding statement to Trusted Policy

```
{
            "Sid": "ECSpermission",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "ecs.amazonaws.com",
                    "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
```

2. Role Permissions:

Adding AWS manged policies:

- AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess
- AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role
- Adding custom inline policy: ( I know permissions is so extensive)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "application-autoscaling:*",
                "resource-groups:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Declare your custom role with the parameter `iam_role` in the resource "aws_ecs_service"

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "team_deployment" {
  name            = local.ecs_task
  cluster         = data.terraform_remote_state.common_resources.outputs.ecs_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.team_deployment.arn
  launch_type     = "EC2"
  iam_role        = "arn:aws:iam::****:role/my_custom_role"

  desired_count = 3
  enable_ecs_managed_tags = true
  force_new_deployment    = true
  scheduling_strategy     = "REPLICA"
  wait_for_steady_state   = false


  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = data.terraform_remote_state.common_resources.outputs.target_group_api.arn
    container_name   = var.ecr_image_tag
    container_port   = var.ecr_image_port
  }
}
```

Of course be careful with the parameter `target_group_arn` value. Must be the target group ARN. Then now is working fine!

```
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 2 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using output of previous command. But the output was empty hence target group arn was empty in the create service call.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong role attached.

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "ECSService" {
  name    = "stage-quotation"
  cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.ECSCluster2.id
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.ElasticLoadBalancingV2TargetGroup2.arn
    container_name   = "stage-quotation"
    container_port   = 8000
  }
  desired_count                      = 1
  task_definition                    = aws_ecs_task_definition.ECSTaskDefinition.arn
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 200
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 100
  iam_role                           = aws_iam_service_linked_role.IAMServiceLinkedRole4.arn #
  ordered_placement_strategy {
    type  = "spread"
    field = "instanceId"
  }
  health_check_grace_period_seconds = 0
  scheduling_strategy               = "REPLICA"
}
```

```
resource "aws_iam_service_linked_role" "IAMServiceLinkedRole2" {
  aws_service_name = "ecs.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
}
resource "aws_iam_service_linked_role" "IAMServiceLinkedRole4" {
  aws_service_name = "ecs.amazonaws.com"
  description      = "Role to enable Amazon ECS to manage your cluster."
}
```

I accidentally used my role for application-autoscaling due to poor naming convention. The correct role we need to use is defined above as `IAMServiceLinkedRole4`.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved by destroying my stack and re-deploying.